# Поле "От кого" в письмах, отправленных с сайта

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы в поле "от кого" был не мой адрес почты, а адрес почты отправителя? Благодарю!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["email"])){
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {$name = $_POST["name"];}
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {$email = $_POST["email"];}

if($name=="" or $email==""){
    echo "Заполните, пожалуйста, все поля!";
}else{
    $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$to = "mail@mail.ru";
$subject = "Заявка!";
$headers = "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8;";
$headers = "From: <mail@mail.ru>";
$message = "Имя: $name\nE-mail: $email\nIP отправителя: $ip"; 
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


 if ($send == "true")
 {
 echo "Поздравляем! Ваша заявка принята!";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!";
 }
}
}
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

В поле `from` должен быть именно адрес почты, от которого почту может отправлять скрипт.

Иначе письмо с неверным адресом отправителя будет расценено как спам (а точнее [спуфинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)). С соответствующими действиями антиспам систем - указанием письма как спам, удалением сразу при получении и вплоть до блокировки приёма любых последующих писем с ваших адресов.

Если вы хотите в письме выразить пожелание программе-получателю письма отправлять ответы на другой адрес - для этого существует специальный стандартный заголовок [`Reply-To`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй:

```
<?php
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');

if ($name = $_POST["name"] && $email = $_POST["email"]){

    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
    $message = "Имя: $name\nE-mail: $email\nIP отправителя: $ip";

    if(mail("mail@mail.ru", "Заявка", $message, $headers))
        echo "Ваша заявка принята";
    else
        echo "Произошла ошибка, повторите попытку снова";

} else
    echo "Пожалуйста, заполните все поля";
?>
```

Мой вариант:

```
<?php
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');

$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if($name = $_POST["name"] && $email = $_POST["email"])
{
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;\r\n";
    $headers .= sprintf("From: %s <%s>\r\n", $name, $email);
    $message = sprintf("Имя: %s\nE-mail: %s\nIP отправителя: %s", $name, $email, $ip);

    printf(mail("admin@site.ru", "Заявка", $message, $headers) ? "Ваша заявка принята" : "Ошибка при отправке");
} else
    printf("Заполните все поля");
?>
```